# If $\hat{f}(a)=p^{-1}\sum_t f(t)\psi_{-a}(t)$, why does $ f(t)=\sum_a \hat{f}(a)\psi_a(t)$?

Tags: number-theory, functions

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$, and let $p$ be a prime such that $f(n+p)=f(n)$ for all $n$. I denote by $\psi_a(t)=\zeta^{at}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity. It might be useful to note $\overline{\psi_a(t)}=\psi_a(-t)=\psi_{-a}(t)$. In what follows, all the sums range from $0$ to $p-1$.

If $\hat{f}(a)=p^{-1}\sum_t f(t)\psi_{-a}(t)$. I want to show
$$
f(t)=\sum_a \hat{f}(a)\psi_a(t).
$$
Directly substituting,
\begin{align*}
\sum_a\left(p^{-1}\sum_t f(t)\psi_{-a}(t)\right)\psi_a(t) &=
\sum_ap^{-1}\sum_tf(t)\psi_{-a}(t)\psi_a(t)\\
&= \sum_a p^{-1}\sum_tf(t)\overline{\psi_a(t)}\psi_a(t)\\
&= \sum_a p^{-1}\sum_tf(t)\vert\psi_a(t)\vert^2\\
&= \sum_ap^{-1}\sum_tf(t)\\
&= pp^{-1}\sum_t f(t)=\sum_t f(t)
\end{align*}

I'm stuck evaluating $\sum_t f(t)$. Is there a way to apply $p$-periodicity to see
$$
\sum_t f(t)=f(t)
$$
if it's even true? Maybe I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same letter for two different variables.  On the LHS $f(t)$, $t$ is a fixed integer.  Now consider the expression you wrote on the right:

$$\sum_a\left(p^{-1}\sum_\color{blue}t f(\color{blue}t)\psi_{-a}(\color{blue}t)\right)\psi_a(\color{red}t).$$

The red $t$ is the same $t$ that appears on the LHS. But the blue $t$ is a completely different animal, just a generic index of summation.  Use a different letter for this different object and your problems will start to go away.

Comment: Thanks Erick, that put me on the right track.